# I can't show Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE in runtime permission

Tags: android, permissions

I'm implementing the runtime permissions in my app but I can't do that show the permission for CALL_PHONE. I need to show two permission, read_contact and call_phone. I can show perfectly read_contact but not call_phone permission.

I'm using the AVD emulator to test it.

Some help will be apreciate!

This is my code:

```
      callPesmission.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                requestCallPhonePermission();
            }
        });

        contactPesmission.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                requestContactsPermission();
            }
        });


 private void requestContactsPermission() {
        String locationPermission = Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;
        int hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), locationPermission);
        String[] permissions = new String[] { locationPermission };
        if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CONTACTS);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "We already have persmission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void requestCallPhonePermission() {
        String callPermission = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
        int hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), callPermission);
        String[] permissions = new String[] { callPermission };
        if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "We already have persmission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CONTACTS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "READ_CONTACTS GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "READ_CONTACTS DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CALL_PHONE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CALL_PHONE GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CALL_PHONE DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forget to add the permission in the manifest.....

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I see nothing wrong with your code right there,

Confirm if it actually is present in manifest.xml.

Dialog won't show if its not present in manifest and might throw security exception if we try to use the feature anyway

Comment: saw your own answer :) happens to the best of us :) Runtime permissions can be a pain

Comment: Yes, absolutly agree

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
private static final int PHONE_CALL_REQUEST=0;
```

and your button

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},PHONE_CALL_REQUEST);
}
else
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+01723915447"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Step 2:

```
<permission
    android:name="mypackage.permission.CALL_PHONE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

**NB:** **mypackage** in Step 2 is your root project package name e.g com.myapp  hence the above in step 2 will become

```
<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.permission.CALL_PHONE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Last Step:
In your Java/Kotin function `Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE` will be available

Answer (score -1):

Use in Oreo,

```
android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

You forgot the `android.` part.

Comment: Probably `android.Manifest` is imported and `READ_CONTACTS` also doesn't have the `android.` part.

Comment: Sorry, you are missing the directory, Manifest, so the compiler can't resolve the rest.